# Deploy ASP.NET MVC on Azure Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, entity-framework, deployment, web-deployment

I make the first deployment of my application on Azure
and I get an error

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
> starting at index 0.

I added to my web.config code to see custom errors, I mean:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

and

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
          <remove statusCode="404" />
          <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/Error404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <remove statusCode="500" />
          <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/Error500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
          <remove statusCode="403" />
          <error statusCode="403" path="/Error/Error403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

I dont really know how to deal with this error.

Link to github:

https://github.com/LNwwv/Memes-Web-site

Link to this websie:

https://memesproject.azurewebsites.net/

[image: Error Screen]

Answer (score 0):

Your `ApplicationDbContext` constructor references a connection string called `DefaultConnection` but your web.Release.config references one called `MemesProject`

Use the same connection string name regardless of the environment and update the value.

Comment: So what I have to change to get a result?  Sory Im really new in deployment and set up connection string to db.

Comment: I changed in web.Release.config to <add name="DefaultConnection"   and still same error

Comment: The error indicates that the connection string is blank or null. Go to the azure portal to your app service -> Advanced Tools -> Debug console, then browse to your web.config and see what the connection string(s) name and value look like.

Comment: `<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=tcp:memesprojectdbserver.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MemesProject_db;User Id=@memesprojectdbserver;Password=[here my password]" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish" connectionString="DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish.ConnetionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>` i found this

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem in publish menu i had to manualy select connection string to database
[image]